# Why is hook_schema() called twice?

Tags: 7, entities, database

I'm working with entities and, in trying to troubleshoot another issue, I noticed that `hook_schema()` is called twice each time the module is installed. This happened even with a bare bones test module containing only a `hook_schema()` definition. My questions are:

- Is it normal for `hook_schema()` to be called twice on module installation?
- Why would `hook_schema()` be called twice on installation?

Comment: Surprisingly interesting question. On the other hand - does it bother you in any way?

Comment: Molot, it doesn't bother me, so long as I know that it isn't a sign of something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be normal. Looking at the [hook_schema](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) documentation, you see that it is invoked in `drupal_get_complete_schema()` in includes/bootstrap.inc and in `drupal_get_schema_unprocessed()` in includes/common.inc. The main difference is that the latter does not invoke `hook_schema_alter()` after the hook_schema is invoked. The first of those functions seems to be called on practically every page load. The second function is called from `drupal_install_schema()` during the module install process.

Concluding, looking at the code it seems to me that:

- It is normal
- It happens because during installation, Drupal needs the un-altered schema definitions

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `hook_schema()` is not just used when a module is installed, and Drupal creates the database tables the module needs. It is also used from other functions or methods that need to know the fields a database table contains. For example, [EntityFieldQuery::propertyQuery()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3ApropertyQuery/7) and [drupal_write_record()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7) use it.

Then, when a module is enabled/installed, Drupal (via [`module_enable()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_enable/7)) invokes `hook_schema()` twice:

- With a call to [`drupal_get_schema(NULL, TRUE)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_schema/7), which invokes `hook_schema()` for every enabled module
- With a call to [`drupal_install_schema($module)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_install_schema/7), which invokes `hook_schema()` for the modules `module_enable()` is enabling

```
  // Refresh the schema to include it.
  drupal_get_schema(NULL, TRUE);
  // Update the theme registry to include it.
  drupal_theme_rebuild();
  // Clear entity cache.
  entity_info_cache_clear();

  // Now install the module if necessary.
  if (drupal_get_installed_schema_version($module, TRUE) == SCHEMA_UNINSTALLED) {
    drupal_install_schema($module);

    // Set the schema version to the number of the last update provided
    // by the module.
    $versions = drupal_get_schema_versions($module);
    $version = $versions ? max($versions) : SCHEMA_INSTALLED;

    // If the module has no current updates, but has some that were
    // previously removed, set the version to the value of
    // hook_update_last_removed().
    if ($last_removed = module_invoke($module, 'update_last_removed')) {
      $version = max($version, $last_removed);
    }
    drupal_set_installed_schema_version($module, $version);
    // Allow the module to perform install tasks.
    module_invoke($module, 'install');
    // Record the fact that it was installed.
    $modules_installed[] = $module;
    watchdog('system', '%module module installed.', array('%module' => $module), WATCHDOG_INFO);
  }
```